# Algorithm problem for Deletion Distance between 2 string

Tags: python

I was solving this problem at Pramp and I have trouble figuring out the algorithm for this problem. I'll paste the problem description and how I kind of solved it. It's the correct solution.  It is similar to the edit distance algorithm and I used the same approach.  I just wanted to see what are other ways to solve this problem.

> The deletion distance of two strings is the minimum number of characters you need to delete in the two strings in order to get the same string. For instance, the deletion distance between "heat" and "hit" is 3:
>
> By deleting 'e' and 'a' in "heat", and 'i' in "hit", we get the string "ht" in both cases.
>   We cannot get the same string from both strings by deleting 2 letters or fewer.
>   Given the strings str1 and str2, write an efficient function deletionDistance that returns the deletion distance between them. Explain how your function works, and analyze its time and space complexities.
>
> Examples:
>   input:  str1 = "dog", str2 = "frog"
>   output: 3
>   input:  str1 = "some", str2 = "some"
>   output: 0
>   input:  str1 = "some", str2 = "thing"
>   output: 9
>   input:  str1 = "", str2 = ""
>   output: 0

What I want to do in this solution, is to use dynamic programming in order to build a function that calculates opt(str1Len, str2Len). Notice the following:
I use dynamic programming methods to calculate opt(str1Len, str2Len), i.e. the deletion distance for the two strings, by calculating opt(i,j) for all 0 ≤ i ≤ str1Len, 0 ≤ j ≤ str2Len, and saving previous values

```
  def deletion_distance(s1, s2):
    m = [[0 for j in range(len(s2) +1)] for i in range(len(s1)+1)] 
    for i in range(len(s1)+1):
      for j in range(len(s2)+1):
        if i == 0:
          m[i][j] = j
        elif j == 0:
          m[i][j] = i
        elif s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
          m[i][j] = m[i-1][j-1]
        else:
          m[i][j] = 1 + min(m[i-1][j], m[i][j-1])
    return m[len(s1)][len(s2)]
```

Comment: That's [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) in disguise.

Comment: Googling for longest common subsequence algorithms doesn't turn up anything better for the 2-sequence case than the straightforward dynamic programming solution, aside from the simple optimization of only keeping one row of the table at a time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.